# Control type datepicker in xsd file adding extra spaces

Tags: css, asp.net, xml, xslt, xsd

The problem looks simple but not able to encounter it. I have a user form developed with XML, XSD and XSLT. In .xsd file datecontrol is adding spaces at both ends

example: 2015-05-06
It goes like this (3 - 4 Space)2015-05-06(3 - 4 Space) and in text field it displays only (3 - 4 Space)20. Remaining part is getting displayed i cannot increase the width of the control. i just want to remove those spaces so that i can see the entire date.

.XSD:

```
<xs:element name="CurrentDate" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" fa:Caption="Current Date" fa:ControlType="DatePicker" fa:Watermark="Date" />
```

.XSLT:

```
<td valign='top' style='border-top:none;border-left:none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt'>
    <p class='Default'>
        <span lang='EN-GB' style='font-size:9.0pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif"; color:#404040'>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="xsd:element[@name='CurrentDate']" mode="addField">
            <xsl:with-param name="width" select="'120pt'"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </span>
    </p>
```

UI:

[image]

Selected date is not properly appearing as its adding spaces in it and i have to literally move the into the field to see the complete date.

[image]

Please help me to understand what is happening and all ideas to resolve will be much appreciated.

ANSWER/ WORKAROUND:

Include the date format in your exd file.

```
<xs:element name="CurrentDate" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" fa:Caption="Current Date" fa:ControlType="DatePicker" fa:Watermark="Date" fa:DateFormat="dd/MM/yy"/>
```

Comment: Is this a browser-related problem rather than a problem with xsd/xslt? Maybe seeing the template being applied or the resultant html/css/js code would help.

Comment: I am trying in all possible ways! thank you @serigoFC

Comment: Maybe I haven't explained it properly. I was trying to say that if you post the code or xsl template maybe we could help you finding a error in the code.